# Silverlight 3: Best way to select a local file for input / upload

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I'm using Silverlight 3 to write a LOB applcation that takes an input file, does some stuff, and then returns an output file. What is the easiest way to get the input file from the user and then return a file back to the user? Can I access the local file system to do this? How? Most likely the files will be ASCII files, but could be Excel some day (Hopefully soon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the local file system *provided* you go via the OpenFileDialog (for reading files) and the SaveFileDialog (for writing files).  You can't access arbitrary files, only the ones where the user has seen and OKed the file dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There is one exception to what [itowlson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61700/itowlson) says, you do have access to IsolatedStorage.  However, this is limited.  Access to "normal" files can only be through interaction of the user.  This makes silverlight a much safer playground, from a user perspective, then older (like activex) technologies.